# Warum gibt es keinen Artikel in diesem Extrakt: »Der Zug wand sich gebogen auf schmalem Paß«

Tags: sentence-structure

In englischer Sprache wäre dies natürlich ohne Artikel falsch. Gibt es eine Regel, die erklärt, wann das Weglassen eines Artikels grammatisch richtig ist?

> Er sah hinaus: der Zug wand sich gebogen auf **schmalem Paß**;

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61552/discussion-on-question-by-user135711-warum-gibt-es-keinen-artikel-in-diesem-extr).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dieser Fall ist *nicht* im engeren Sinne grammatikalisch korrekt, sondern ein Stilmittel (Ellipsis), das den Satz "schlanker" klingen lässt (passend zum Bild des Zuges).

Strukturen dieser Art sind teilweise noch heute in Gebrauch (ich habe allerdings gerade kein gutes Beispiel zur Hand - Edit: *auf schmalem Grat* ist ein gutes), aber wenn, dann nur noch in idiomatischen Ausdrücken, die in der Regel ebenfalls aus einer literarischen Quelle stammen. Es gibt keine Regel, die sie erlauben würde.

---

This case is not strictly gramatically correct, it's a poetic figure of speech (ellipsis) to make the sentence sound more "slim" (corresponding to the image of the train).

Some similar structures may still be used in today's spoken language (I have no good example at hand - *auf schmalem Grat* is a good one), but only in idiomatic expressions that usually stem from a literary source as well. There is no actual rule that allows this.

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einem Deutschforum auf eine in Deutsch formulierte Frage, die Aspekte der deutschen Sprache zum Inhalt hat, in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: Das ist eine gute Frage.

Comment: Ist wohl ein unbewusster Reflex auf die englischsprachigen Kommentare. Und so eine zweischneidige Sache.. ich schätze mal, der Fragestelle versteht eine englischsprachige Antwort besser/schneller - dafür lernt er von einer deutschsprachigen natürlich mehr. Ich habs mal übersetzt.

Comment: @Annatar Dann wäre eine Möglichkeit, sowohl die deutsche Antwort als auch die englische Übersetzung zu posten. Da du die ja noch hast, könntest du sie noch (wieder) ergänzen?

Comment: Danke fürs Übersetzen. Der Fragesteller hat sich ja extra die Mühe gemacht, seine Frage auf Deutsch zu formulieren. Wenn jemand das tut, und offenbar auch in der Lage ist, Thomas Mann zu lesen, dann ist davon auszugehen, dass er eine deutschsprachige Antwort erwartet, und dass er sie auch verstehen wird.

Comment: Ja, wohl wahr. Ich finds übrigens gut, wenn jemand bei anderen darauf achtet (Daumen hoch). Ich vergess glaub ich öfters mal, die Sprache zu wechseln, wenn ich vorher noch in einer anderen Community unterwegs war..

Comment: *Auf dünnem Eis* ist ein anderer Fall, denn *Eis* ist hier unzählbar, so dass die Konstruktion auch ohne Adjektiv korrekt ist, *auf schmalem Pass* benötigt hingegen das *schmal*.

Comment: Nimm einfach "auf schmalem Grat", hier hat sich die artikellose Konstruktion in einem stehenden Ausdruck erhalten. (und wir bleiben nah am Paß)

Comment: @CarstenS: Und wo wir dabei sind: Das gilt allgemein für **Unzählbares**, und ist dabei auch vollkommen korrekt. Ich mag nämlich **Eis**, und **Schokolade** schmeckt mir auch. Doch damit nicht genug: Auch bei zählbaren Dingen kann das richtig sein, und zwar, weil ich ohne **Jacke**, aber mit **Sonnenbrille** bei **sonniger Wetterlage** im Freien sitze, auf meiner mit **Stuhl** und **Tisch** versehenen Terrasse.

Answer (score 4):

Of course one could set an indefinite article here without change of meaning. I guess it is omitted to emphasize the arbitrariness of the *Paß* in question, it is intended as an abstract as would be in

> Du bewegst dich auf abschüssigem Weg / unsicherem Terrain / dünnem Eis

Abstracts justify the so-called *Nullartikel* and specifications of material (as here Eis and Terrain) are mostly used abstracts.

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einem Deutschforum auf eine in Deutsch formulierte Frage, die Aspekte der deutschen Sprache zum Inhalt hat, in einer Fremdsprache?

Comment: Ein UN-bestimmter Artikel würde wohl nicht in diesen Satz mit dem Pass passen, sondern nur ein bestimmter, weil hier einen ganz bestimmten, realen und konkreten Pass gemeint worden ist. Deine andere Beispiele sind jedoch in überführter Meinung gemeint und hier würde der unbestimmte Artikel besser passen

Comment: @Beta glaube ich nicht. Der *spezifische, konkrete und reale* Pass ist für die Geschichte volkommen unwichtig, es geht nur darum, dass er *schmal* ist - Deswegen passt auch ein unbestimmter Artikel prima.

Comment: Danke, Dann verstehe ich das noch besser;  siehe meine Antwort unten

Answer (score 2):

Mann hat hier natürlich nicht nur ein Stilmittel verwendet um den Satz gut  klingen zu lassen, und weil es für ihn die Möglichkeit gab es zu verwenden. Er hat das Mittel vielmehr genau an einer Stelle verwendet wo wir auf einen Weg denken, hier den Pass, denn die andere Beispiele, die im allgemeinen Sprachbrauch vorkommen, ("dünnem Eis","unsicherm Terrain" etc) beziehen sich auch auf Wege, unz zwar in überführen Bedeutungen. Mit diesem Griff hat Mann uns sehr raffiniert dazu gebracht, dass wir verstehen, dies sei nicht nur ein enger Pass, sondern ein Weg, auf dem Hans Castorp nicht nur zufällig gebracht worden ist, ein Weg der schmal und gewunden ist. 
In meiner schwedischen Übersetzung sieht man nichts von dies.